# Nginx proxy pass without rewrite url

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, jwilder-nginx-proxy

```
        location /checks/ {
                auth_request /auth;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/meetings;
        }

        location = /auth {
          internal;
          set $query '';
          if ($request_uri ~* "[^\?]+\?(.*)$") {
              set $query $1;
          }
          proxy_pass http://localhost:9000/v1/permission/check?$query;
          proxy_pass_request_body   off;
          proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        }
```

I have setup my nginx as above.

**Description:** I call to the url: http://my-domain.com/checks?abc=123 on browser, after passing auth_request, it will redirect to http://my-domain.com/meetings?abc=123

**Error:** Can not proxy_pass to http://localhost:3000/meetings.
Error from nginx log: `*1 localhost could not be resolved (60: Operation timed out) while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /checks/?abc=123`

**Expectations:** fix the error above and proxy_pass to http://my-domain.com/meetings but do not rewrite the old URL, which means keep http://my-domain.com/checks on browser

**Note:** ?abc=123 just example

**Please help me**

Comment: try replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1 and let's see if it is DNS issue

Comment: @Husseinfo thank you for your help, but I can not solve it. have another solution? thank